# Show images side by side in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show some images side by side from an album with matplotlib in my jupyter notebook.

I wrote a function but it doesnt work.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show(path):
    for iter in list.get(path):
        img = cv2.imread(images)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use subplot function for every image:

```
plt.subplot(2, 2, n) # n is the position of your subplot (1 to 4)
plt.imshow(img)
```

When you finished loading all subplot, just call:

```
plt.show()
```

Below I made a simple example that might help you, you can find the Jupyter notebook for this file in my [github repo](https://github.com/leomariga/StackOverflowSolutions/blob/master/side-side%20figures.ipynb):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("a"+".jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.imshow(img)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image: sideside]

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong.  First, you are overwriting `list` and `iter`, which are two of the built-in callables.  It is best practice to not do that.  I am not sure what the variable `list` is, but it looks to be a dictionary since it implements the `.get` method.

The main issue you are having is that you are creating a new set of images/axes with each iteration of your loop.

You should define the image and axes outside of the for loop and iterate over the axes along with the images you want to plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from glob import glob

def plot_album(album_name):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
    # this assumes the images are in images_dir/album_name/<name>.jpg
    image_paths = glob(images_dir + album_name + '/*.jpg')
    for imp, ax in zip(image_paths, axes.ravel()):
        img = mpimg.imread(imp)
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]